# How to center a div with transition animation

Tags: javascript, css

This is demo: [Demo](http://jsbin.com/ucosup/8/edit)
The demo will work only on webkit browsers, (chrome or safari)

There are four box, each have a title. When users clicks to expand the div. The div is made to expand. Initially the title is in left, but when the div is expanded the title must move to center with animation.I have made the div to align center using padding, but there is a problem, that for varying text-width the padding has to be changed to make the title properly centered. Please take a look at the code, you will understand it better

Comment: the problem is that initially the title are to left aligned and on expanding the div the title has to be centered.How that can be done with animation. Now i have used display-inline for the title, and on expanding the div, i increase the left-padding of the title to make the title look center aligned. But the problem with this technique is that for different text length the padding should be changed to make to title exactly centred

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the padding, center the title on the h3 and try to animate the width of the title between auto and 100%; Use the nowrap to make sure the title stays on one line.

```
h3 {
  text-align: center;
  width: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  ...
}
```

Then animate to

```
.expand h3 {
  width: 100%;
}
```